# Displaying value of object

Tags: json, object, meteor

I am getting a JSON data from mongodb , when I alert that variable , it shows me the result as "object object". Now I want to view the exact values of the "object object". How could I do that...?
Can any one suggest solution other than JSON.stringify()....?

Answer (score 2):

An object being used as an associative array can be iterated using:

```
for (var key in thevar) { 
    console.log(key + ": " + thevar[key]); 
}
```

which will produce output like:

```
_id: 793fdda7-3f2d-48c8-8e82-f2471f411d24
tag: example
ram: 8kb
```